# blazor dynamically change css on mouseover when multible divs are displayed

Tags: css, parameters, blazor, element, onmouseover

```
@foreach (var item in RootOfJson.results)
{
<div class="card" @onmouseout="@OnMouseOut" @onmouseover="@OnMouseOver"> 
<img class="@Imgdisplay" src=@item.image_url  alt="...">                                            
</div>
}
    

@code {

bool _IsHovering = false;
[Parameter]
public string Imgdisplay { get; set; }

 protected void OnMouseOver(MouseEventArgs mouseEvent)
    {
        if (!_IsHovering)
        {
            _IsHovering = true;     
            Imgdisplay = "d-none";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnMouseOut(MouseEventArgs mouseEvent)
    {       
        Imgdisplay = String.Empty;        
        _IsHovering = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Above code changes the css for all divs, can you assist.. i would like to change the class to d-none on the specific div that my mouse event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

When you go over some `div`, method `OnMouseOver` is called, it sets `_IsHovering` to `true` and `Imgdisplay` to `"d-none"`. All your `div` elements use `_IsHovering`. That's why css for all `div` elements is changed.

I think it would be a good idea to create separate component and put `div` with things it uses (e.g. `_IsHovering` or `Imgdisplay`) there. This way each `div` will "work on its own" and will not share the state.